# Duplicate a Mongodb Collection but with a `limit` applied

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to have a second Collection that is exactly the same as the first Collection, but with a `limit` and `sort` operator applied to it?

If the first Collection have 1000+ records and have new records being added, the second Collection will have all the new records, but limited to N newest records (sort by timestamp field).

The reason for doing this is to overcome a limitation in my database driver that does not have `sort` and `limit` implemented yet.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is a [capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/).

A capped collection is automatically limited to a fixed amount of records. When they are full and you add a new document, the oldest document is deleted. All records are guaranteed to be in insertion order when you query from the collection without an explicit sort. The biggest limitation is that documents in a capped collection can not be updated when that would increase their size.

Capped collections need to be created explicitely with the createCollection function. This shell command would create a capped collection limited to 1000 documents:

```
db.createCollection( "your_collection_name", { capped: true, size: 1000 } );
```

When you want to convert an already existing collection to a capped collection, you can use the convertToCapped database command:

```
db.runCommand({"convertToCapped": "your_existing_collection_name", size: 1000});
```